# Pure Javascript how to hide multiple element using one click

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a html accordion and everything is working great. But I am trying to make it so, when you click to expand one of the accordion buttons, its content will expand (show) AND all other accordion content will be hidden.

So if I click accordion one, content for accordion two and three should be hidden, and only content for the click accordion (accordion one) will show.

I would like to do this in pure javascript. I do not want to use JQuery **`$("p").hide();`,** as I am doing a pure javascript build THANKS :)

**MY CODE**

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;">
  <p>Content one</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;">
  <p>Content two</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;">
  <p>Content three</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: you sould have to visit this link - https://codepen.io/sureshrkm/pen/ZbzBpr

Comment: @KaushikAndani thanks for finding this

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can first hide all other panels & then display current panel.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        currentDisplay = panel.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
        //hide all panels
        [].forEach.call(els, function (el) {
          el.style.display = 'none';
        });
        //display current panel
        panel.style.display = currentDisplay;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;">
    <p>Content one</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;">
    <p>Content two</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel" style="display:none;">
    <p>Content three</p>
</div>



  <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                //  this.classList.toggle("active");
                var allPanels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

                for (var i = 0, j = allPanels.length; i < j; i++) {
                    if (allPanels[i].style.display == "block") {
                        allPanels[i].style.display = "none"
                    }
                }
                panel.style.display = "block";

            });
        }
</script>
```